# Rails_Admin - how to export specific rows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin

My Table contains rows, each row has an account field containing the email of the current_user so that users have access only to rows containing their own data. Rails_Admin exports successfully ALL rows. How could I export ONLY the rows that belongs to the user email account.
I am new in .haml

Comment: You might want to take a look at other questions asked on stack overflow for examples on what information to include and how to format it. Especially: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Add your code so that we can see what you have so far.

Comment: Your Question is not clear enough ! try to share some code or data to get the answer quickly . BTW Why don't you filter the data based on that specefic user and then export ?

Comment: I first installed this gem: https://github.com/stephskardal/rails_admin_import and then this one https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin. First gem gives the codes for importing from a file xlsx or csv. Second Gem gives an admin console ready to use. Do you know those gems? As it is not written in a common ruby syntax I'm lost. I just want the rails admin to deal with specific rows.

Comment: I can export successfully all data of any table, I can also import but it creates rows and new IDs but the fields are NULL.

Comment: to Afsane, could you show me a script that would filter before export, and were to put it in rails_admin tree. I didn't wrote any code the both gem installed a rails_admin folder in my views, controller.. and 10 new gems came along. bundle and rake assets that is all I did.

Answer (score -1):

You can select which fields to export by defining the export block

```
RailsAdmin.config do |config|
  config.model 'Highway' do
    export do
      field :number_of_lanes
    end
  end
end
```

Also you can configure the value of each field

```
  RailsAdmin.config do |config|
    config.model 'Lesson' do 
      export do
        field :teacher, :string do
          export_value do
            value.name if value #value is an instance of Teacher
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: But I do not want to export specific field but specific rows. For example all rows where field Account = curent_user.email. Normally I do that: 
@myselected_items = Contact.where("Account = ?", current_user.email). But with rails_admin written in .haml I'm lost.

Comment: It doesn't answer the question. It looks like just a paste from the documentation on the github page.

Comment: This is probably the correct response from Guillermo Siliceo too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48011662/filter-export-result-by-email-in-rails-admin/48025126#48025126