# filter export result by email in rails admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-admin

I am trying to filter the the data to be exported in the csv file that rails admin will generate but I want to only export data for a particular email so that no other users can export another person's data.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to implement your own export action to do this. I won't be that hard since you can just copy paste the existing one found in 
https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/blob/master/lib/rails_admin/config/actions/export.rb

In your own project root create the file

```
/lib/rails_admin/config/actions/export.rb
```

From there you have the current_user variable available and you can scope the objects like so:

```
@objects = list_entries(@model_config, :export).select { |object| object.user_id == current_user.id }
```

Comment: i tried that but it seems like rails doesn't recognise the code in the file. It doesn't end up being run

Comment: Have you tried restarting the server? if you are running spring, make sure you do spring stop so it reloads the code.
Also you will need to add the autoload configuration to your application.rb if you don't have it already:     config.autoload_paths << Rails.root.join('lib')